# Android Studio & Gradle: Add outside java classes to Android main project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have some java classes that sits in it's own directory outside the main project (but in the same project folder).

The folder setup looks like this:

```
root
 |
 |
 |- Main project
 |
 |- Dir
 |   |-src
 |   |-libs
 |
 |- more android libs...
```

I want to include the Dir/src classes in the Main Project.

I've tried this in the Gradle build files:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src', ':Dir/src']
...
```

To no avail.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to make your `Dir` a own module

add `include 'Dir'` to your settings.gradle

create a build.gradle inside your `Dir` directory with this content `apply plugin: java`

now you can go into your main projects `build.gradle` and add to dependencies: `compile project(':Dir')`

---

if your `Dir` uses android related stuff, you might want to use the `New > Module`(right click on your project in Android Studio) Function of Android Studio to create an Android Library.

But i haven't tested that feature yet. If Android Studio throws an Exception when trying to use the New Module, you should try to update Android Studio, in the latest Version it works for me.

---

You might also want to check the Gradle [User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html) and the [DSL Reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) both are very helpfull in getting into Gradle and understanding it.

Comment: Actually manage to figure this out before you posted your answer, but thanks for additional tips. This is by far the best way to go.
Thx again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm building on Dodge's answer and actually post the Gradle code that fixed this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
targetCompatibility = '1.6'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
           srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}

buildDir = 'bin'
```